# Prevent toolbar from being added to context menu

Tags: pyqt, pyside

I am creating a custom toolbar which automatically adds itself to the parent (if present) when initialized.

I would like this custom toolbar to *not* appear in the context menu.  However, something (I don't know what) related to the toolbar shows up, despite using `setContextMenuPolicy` :

[image]

I can't tell what that context menu item is.  My understanding is that any widget, by way of its contextMenuPolicy, can be added to the context menu.  Yet there isn't any other widget within the CustomToolBar.

A workaround is to disable the context menu altogether on the MainWindow and create a menu item (e.g. View) which toggles visibility.

```py
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class CustomToolBar(QtWidgets.QToolBar):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        if parent:
            self.setParent(parent)
            self.parent().addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.BottomToolBarArea, self)

        self.setObjectName('Custom ToolBar')
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.counter = 0
        self.resize(250, 75)

        self.init_widgets()
        self.init_layout()

    def init_widgets(self):

        self.exit_action = QtWidgets.QAction('&Exit', self)
        self.exit_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exit_action.setToolTip('Exit application')
        self.exit_action.triggered.connect(self.close)

        self.menu = self.menuBar()

        self.menu_file = self.menu.addMenu('&File')
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.exit_action)

        # setting parent to self embeds the custom toolbar in the main window
        self.status = CustomToolBar(self)

    def init_layout(self):
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: The image does not illustrate correctly if you are clicking on the menuBar or the lower toolBar.

Some widgets don't override the contextMenuEvent method so using `self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)` won't work, and that's the case with the QToolBar (and the QMenuBar as well). In those cases the event method must be override and rejected.

Assuming you just want it not to appear in the QToolBar then just use:

```py
class CustomToolBar(QtWidgets.QToolBar):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        if isinstance(parent, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
            self.setParent(parent)
            parent.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.BottomToolBarArea, self)

        self.setObjectName('Custom ToolBar')

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ContextMenu:
            return True
        return super().event(event)
```

If you also want to do the same for the MenuBar you have to implement a similar logic:

```py
class StatusBar(QtWidgets.QMenuBar):
    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ContextMenu:
            return True
        return super().event(event)
```

Finally, it is advisable to use names that indicate what type of widget it is, so I will change menu to menu_bar:

```py
def init_widgets(self):

    self.exit_action = QtWidgets.QAction('&Exit', self)
    self.exit_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
    self.exit_action.setToolTip('Exit application')
    self.exit_action.triggered.connect(self.close)

    self.menu_bar = StatusBar()
    self.setMenuBar(self.menu_bar)

    self.menu_file = self.menu_bar.addMenu('&File')
    self.menu_file.addAction(self.exit_action)

    # setting parent to self embeds the custom toolbar in the main window
    self.tool_bar = CustomToolBar(self)
```

Update:

It seems that the objective of the OP is that the QAction associated with the QToolBar implemented in the QMenu of QMainWindow is not shown, so for this it is better to override the createPopupMenu method and remove the QAction and for this it is not necessary to implement a custom QToolBar.

```py
import sys
import uuid

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_widgets()
        self.init_layout()

    def init_widgets(self):

        self.exit_action = QtWidgets.QAction("&Exit", self)
        self.exit_action.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        self.exit_action.setToolTip("Exit application")
        self.exit_action.triggered.connect(self.close)

        self.menu_bar = self.menuBar()

        self.menu_file = self.menu_bar.addMenu("&File")
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.exit_action)

        self.custom_toolbar = QtWidgets.QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.BottomToolBarArea, self.custom_toolbar)
        self.custom_toolbar.setProperty("hide_action_toolbar", True)

        self.dock = QtWidgets.QDockWidget("Dock")
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.TopDockWidgetArea, self.dock)

    def init_layout(self):
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

    def createPopupMenu(self):
        titles = []
        for toolbar in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QToolBar):
            if toolbar.property("hide_action_toolbar") is None:
                continue
            if toolbar.property("hide_action_toolbar"):
                toolbar.setProperty("last_window_title", toolbar.windowTitle())
                toolbar.setWindowTitle(uuid.uuid4().hex)
                titles.append(toolbar.windowTitle())
            else:
                toolbar.setWindowTitle(toolbar.property("last_window_title") or "")
        menu = super().createPopupMenu()
        for action in menu.actions():
            if action.text() in titles:
                menu.removeAction(action)
        return menu


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.resize(640, 480)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I appreciate the update.  It still doesn't do quite what I want, but I believe that's Qt/Python, not you!  It appears the only way to have the CustomToolBar perform the removal is through monkey patching.  As you point out, that can be dangerous.  I'm accepting this because it answers the question as written, I appreciate your time and effort, and I learned something.  Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The item showing up in the context menu is, in fact, the toolbar.  The menu item comes from the corresponding action text.  This, in turn, comes from the toolbar window title.  Since this is an empty string by default, it shows as blank in the menu.

Changing the line `self.setObjectName('Custom ToolBar')` to `self.setWindowTitle('Custom ToolBar')` will show the toolbar name, as expected.

[image]

```py
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class CustomToolBar(QtWidgets.QToolBar):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, title='CustomToolBar'):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        # Sets the action text in the context menu
        self.setWindowTitle(title)

        if parent:
            self.setParent(parent)
            self.parent().addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.BottomToolBarArea, self)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.counter = 0
        self.resize(250, 75)

        self.init_widgets()
        self.init_layout()

    def init_widgets(self):

        self.exit_action = QtWidgets.QAction('&Exit', self)
        self.exit_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exit_action.setToolTip('Exit application')
        self.exit_action.triggered.connect(self.close)

        # self.menu_bar = CustomMenuBar()
        # self.setMenuBar(self.menu_bar)
        self.menu_bar = self.menuBar()

        self.menu_file = self.menu_bar.addMenu('&File')
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.exit_action)

        # self embeds the toolbar in the main window
        self.status = CustomToolBar(self)

    def init_layout(self):
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()

    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As for the CustomToolBar not appearing in the context menu, that's more complicated.  One option is to use a custom context menu via the parent (i.e. MainWindow).  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781313/5065796) explains how that can be done.

However, wanting to have the CustomToolBar automatically remove itself is better for the user, but more of a challenge. The context menu is actually created on the fly by the QMainWindow via the [`createContextPopupMenu`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781313/5065796) method.  The CustomToolBar has to override this method such that it removes itself from the resulting list.  Ideally, this should be done in a way that preserves the context menu's behavior.

The `createContextPopupMenu` method is called by the MainWindow's [`contextMenuEvent` handler](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython-5.15/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWidget.html?highlight=contextmenuevent#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.contextMenuEvent).  So, using the fact that Python treats functions as first class citizens, we can replace the `createPopupMenu` method with a version that removes the CustomToolBar from it.  The following example has added a QDockWidget to demonstrate that the CustomToolBar has removed itself.

[image]

```py
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class CustomToolBar(QtWidgets.QToolBar):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, title='CustomToolBar'):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        # Sets the action text in the context menu
        self.setWindowTitle(title)

        if parent:
            self.setParent(parent)
            self.parent().addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.BottomToolBarArea, self)

            ############################################################
            # Remove the custom toolbar from the parent's context menu #
            ############################################################
            original_popup = self.parent().createPopupMenu
            original_handler = self.parent().contextMenuEvent

            # Create custom contextMenuEvent which repurposes the
            # original createPopupMenu method through use of closures
            def customContextMenuEvent(event):

                def custom_popup():
                    popup = original_popup()

                    # Because this is being handled by CustomToolBar,
                    # which adds itself to the MainWindow, there is
                    # guaranteed to be at least one item
                    for action in popup.actions():
                        if action.text() == self.windowTitle():
                            popup.removeAction(action)
                    return popup

                # call the original handler with its call to
                # createPopupMenu sneakily replaced with our own
                self.parent().createPopupMenu = custom_popup
                original_handler(event)

            # Replace the MainWindow's contextMenuEvent with our own
            self.parent().contextMenuEvent = customContextMenuEvent

        # Prevents right click on CustomToolBar from showing context menu
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.PreventContextMenu)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.counter = 0
        self.resize(250, 75)

        self.init_widgets()
        self.init_layout()

    def init_widgets(self):

        self.exit_action = QtWidgets.QAction('&Exit', self)
        self.exit_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exit_action.setToolTip('Exit application')
        self.exit_action.triggered.connect(self.close)

        self.menu_bar = self.menuBar()

        self.menu_file = self.menu_bar.addMenu('&File')
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.exit_action)

        # self embeds the status toolbar in the main window
        self.status = CustomToolBar(self)

        self.dock = QtWidgets.QDockWidget('Dock')
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.TopDockWidgetArea, self.dock)


    def init_layout(self):
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()

    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Don't do `foo.fooEvent = some_function` as some may fail. PyQt (and also PySide) caches these methods so if the same logic applies elsewhere in your code then your solution will fail.

Comment: On the other hand, your code is dangerous since for example a QToolBar can have a parent to QWidget so invoking `self.parent().addToolBar` can throw an exception. In my code I verify that the parent is a QMainWindow.

Comment: I appreciate the heads up.  With that knowledge in hand, and a clear example of the desired behavior, is there a safe way to achieve the same outcome?  When I ran your code, I did not observe the outcome I expected.

Comment: mmm, my code prevents the popup from showing and isn't that what you expected?

Comment: Maybe you have not implemented my demo correctly. To make it more visible I have set the background color of the QToolBar to red so if you right click the popup will not be shown. https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/6590727e5e30db8df2025b8a7c2ee35d

Comment: Thank you for taking the extra effort to write up full a Gist.  There may be a miscommunication.  I don't want the CustomToolBar to appear in *any* context menu; the one that appears by right clicking the toolbar  as well as the menu bar.  When I run your Gist (with PyQt5.12.3), only the toolbar context is removed.  Both the Dock and the CustomWidget (with no name) appear in the menu bar.  Maybe I am mistaken and the menu that appears when right clicking on the menu bar is not called a context menu?

Comment: re: dangerous b/c of caching, I found this in the old bug tracker: https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-bz-archive/533.html I could not find it or a similar issue in the current Qt bug tracker.  I read that to mean any methods created by PySide/PyQt should be fine.  I agree, though, that it might be wise to avoid this approach as it's not guaranteed across all implementations (assuming nothing has changed in the 10+ years since that issue was filed).

Comment: So you understand: Let's say we simplify code a lot and we get the following: `some_widget.contextMenuEvent = method1` and after showing the window you do`some_widget.contextMenuEvent = method2`, what method will be invoked after right clicking:  method1 or  metho2?

Comment: Fair enough.  Monkey patching has its pitfalls. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27466499/5065796 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch#Pitfalls (We both know this; links for anyone else reading who doesn't) :)